# how to use callback function in angular 4?

Tags: angularjs, angular, function, callback

I have used to get current address using google api and now i want implement callback function in this function using angular 4 how can implement it?

```
 let currgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   currgeocoder.geocode({
      'location': location
   }, function(results:any, status:any) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        let place = results[0];
       //this.showresult(place.formatted_address);
      } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
   });

      this.myGroup.setValue({
      searchControl: 'global'
    });
```

Comment: have look to my answer if you need any thing let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create oberservable and push new values on it ,

```
let subject = new Subject(); 
let ovservable = subject.asObservable()

subject.next("b");

ovservable.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log("Subscription got", value); // Subscription wont get 
                                          // anything at this point
});
```

so create observable , expose it and when you receive data from call make use of `.next()` method that will do

---

in your code

```
let subject = new Subject(); 
let ovservable = subject.asObservable();
let currgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   currgeocoder.geocode({
      'location': location
   }, function(results:any, status:any) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        let place = results[0];
        subject.next(place);
       //this.showresult(place.formatted_address);
      } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
   });

      this.myGroup.setValue({
      searchControl: 'global'
    });

    ovservable.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log("Subscription got", value); // Subscription wont get 
                                              // anything at this point
    });
```

Comment: i want to pass results[0] value in showresult function so how can do that?

Comment: what is asObservable()? do i need to import any library?

Comment: i am getting this error in cmd:
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Subject'.

Comment: @dgpoo - please import RXJs library in you angular project

Comment: @dgpoo - you cna call you furnction for this   ovservable.subscribe((value) => { yourfunction()});

Comment: yes now it working by importing
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

Comment: Thanks, but I just try it, but not working, need click action to screen to work